# In Flutter, how to create an *empty* two dimensional array of class?

Tags: list, flutter

I have read from this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-multi-dimensional-list-in-dart-78ff332430a) about n-dimensional List in Flutter. But I don't know how to create an empty growable 2D array/list that can grow both the first and second dimension. How can I do that? And after I create it, how can I add a new growable row element to the first dimension?

I'm thinking about things like:

```
List<List<MyClass>> data = []
```

But this don't work, as IDE says that "List is not a type". Then from the article, I tried to use this:

```
var lines = List.generate(0, (i) => List.generate(0, (j) => MyClass(), growable: true), growable: true);
```

While MyClass has content like this:

```
class MyClass {
    double x;
    double y;
    status int;
    MyClass({ this.x, this.y, this.status });
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in dartpad after fixing the `status int` typo in your `MyClass`. Provide your custom static analysis rules if those exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`final myclasses = <List<MyClass>>[[]];`
or
`List<List<MyClass>> myclasses2 = [[]];`
may be the answer, I think :)

But I think, the first one is better.
Second one might be warned by lint.

Comment: Sorry, I just have the time to actually try your solution today, but yeah the first one actually works. I guess I got confused between the first one and the second one, like two entirely different ways to initialize a variable that dart can do. The second one doesn't work though, it's warned by the lint. Thanks!